# how to track ajax request in IE as we do using firebug in FF?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-6

i have a page i.e. [banerbuzz](http://www.bannerbuzz.com) open it in IE-6 here you will find the Instant price box where Size drop down will show only one size, where as if same url is executed in FF you will find the real drop down box which is needed.

i think this could be the issue of path given in ajax file

please help me or suggest me to resolve this issue

Comment: Does it have the same problem in IE7 or IE8? If so, have you tried to use the Developer Tools in IE7/8 to help find it? You may also try testing in Safari, as it may be that you have a problem that FF is just ignoring that IE actually cares about.

Comment: Man you site is horrible in IE. Literally takes 2 minutes to download all of the images. I had to double check to make sure my proxy was not acting like a dial up. lol

Comment: Thanks man for the revert.... m working on the optimization of site will be live soon..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great way to debug Ajax applications on windows.